# Present Progressive for story telling

Tags: writing

I know we can use present simple tense for story telling even in the sentences with the meaning of continous tense but I'm not sure that I can use present continous tense.

For example: I'm walking in the street. I'm completely lost. Suddenly I'm seeing a friend and asking where this street goes. So, I find my way.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about how to tell stories belong at [Writing.SE](https://writing.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I changed it. Thank you for your concern.

Comment: What are you asking? Is it a yes/no question? Please clarify.

Comment: This style of writing **exists** in English. [Here](https://www.really-learn-english.com/english-short-stories-present-progressive-paying-attention.html) is a short story written in the present progressive: _Four-year-old Diego **is playing** in the pool. His mother, Darlene, **is sitting** in the sun beside the pool. She **is reading** a book. At least, she **is trying** to read a book._ And the story continues...